# Optimize mysql query to retrieve time series data

Tags: sql, mysql, node.js, time-series, query-optimization

I have following timeseries data table,

| Id | Object_Id | Datetime | Sensor1 | Sensor2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 175 | '2022-03-24 22:01:00' | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 175 | '2022-03-24 22:02:00' | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 175 | '2022-03-24 22:03:00' | 5.5699381666667 | 81.342836833333 |
| 4 | 175 | '2022-03-24 22:04:00' | 5.5668366666667 | 81.281143 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 48 | 175 | '2022-03-24 22:48:00' | NULL | NULL |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

in above table, I have **sensor1**, **sensor2** upto **sensor1000** columns and each has millions of time series records.

**Scenario1:**

I want to retrieve starttime(min datetime) and endtime(max datetime) records for multiple sensors `eg. sensor1 & sensor2` where their value **IS NOT NULL**.

I constructed below query for Sensor1,

```
(SELECT   
    datetime,id,sensor1
FROM   
    timeseries
WHERE  
    sensor1 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY  
    datetime ASC limit 1)

Union ALL

(SELECT   
    datetime,id,sensor1
FROM   
    timeseries
WHERE  
    sensor1 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY  
    datetime DESC limit 1)
```

I constructed below query for Sensor2,

```
(SELECT   
    datetime,id,sensor2
FROM   
    timeseries
WHERE  
    sensor2 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY  
    datetime ASC limit 1)

Union ALL

(SELECT   
    datetime,id,sensor2
FROM   
    timeseries
WHERE  
    sensor2 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY  
    datetime DESC limit 1)
```

This query works as expected. Pls observe that I created individual query for **sensor1** and **sensor2** as I want to handle failure scenario for individual sensor.

Problem is in real life scenario, I have millions of records, around **50 to 70 GB data**.

When I run above query (for just **sensor1** & **sensor2**), it takes significant amount of time to return the result. What if user is trying with multiple sensors. Trust me it takes time and we can observe it in real implementation.

In this **[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/sLldGBv1)** it works smoothly as It has only 150 records.

I need help to improve/optimize the performance of this above query.

FYI, for each requested sensor, query is prepared in **Node/express** app and then app connects to MYSql server where I execute each query using for loop

```
const queryResults = await Promise.all(
      queries.map(async (query) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
          db.query(query, [], (err, result) => {
            if (err) {

              return resolve([]);                // If individual query fails then return empty array
            } else {
    
              return resolve(result);
            }
          })
        );
      })
    );
```

Comment: Is there a reason why the table is denormalized like that? Generally I'd model this as  `(object_id, sensor_id, timestamp, value)`...

Comment: I agree but we have a few old existing time series tables that can't be altered.

Comment: Looking at your example data, is it correct that you have multiple, comma-separated values in each Sensor column?

Comment: Do you have compound indexes for datetime,sensor1 / datetime,sensor2 etc, and an index for datetime also do you have to retrieve all the timeseries data for a given sensor at once? one way  to reduce time to execute would be to fetch only a small data set,

Comment: @RobEyre No No. That is a typo. You can check demo that has proper data.

Comment: @v1shva No we don't have indexing introduced for any column. It is a simple table only.

Comment: Try to create an index by `(Datetime)`.

Comment: For query optimization questions, please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for this table and include the result in your question. Otherwise we have to guess at the indexes you have in this table. Also run `EXPLAIN` for the query and include that.

Comment: What do you want if `sensor1 IS NULL AND senaort2 IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: And..  Is `WHERE object_id=175` on the queries (but not shown)?

Comment: And... That looks like readings every minute, which would ad up to 500K rows/year.  Is that correct?  How many years of data do you have?  Are there always 100 sensor; if not how many are typically NULL?

Comment: @RickJames Ideally it stores each 10 seconds data that way we have millions of records. Typically 100 sensors won't be there in a single table but yes we have many sensors. It varies but different tables may have around 30-40 sensors.

Answer (score 0):

This would run twice as fast (but have different output):

```
SELECT  datetime, id, sensor1, sensor2
    FROM  timeseries
    WHERE  sensor1 IS NOT NULL
       OR  sensor2 IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY  datetime ASC
    limit  1
```

I suspect that your "sensor1" and "sensor2" could be any of 1...1000?  If that is the case, there is no way to use "sensorN" in an index.

So, the best you can do with indexing (either for `UNION` or my suggestion) is `INDEX(datetime)`.  Slightly better would be to have `datetime as the first column of the` PRIMARY KEY`, but I do not like that.  I would prefer dropping` id` and having

```
PRIMARY KEY(object_id, sensor_num, datetime)
```

and make sure that there are no duplicate datetime values.  Note that `DATETIME` will have 60 minutes of dups once a year! -- Consider using `TIMESTAMP` instead.

Only very rarely are the 16 digits of precision of `CDOUBLE` needed; suggest changing to `FLOAT` to cut the table size almost in half.  (Double: 8 bytes; Float: 4 bytes, 7 significant digits).

If there are lots of `NULLs` and/or the number of sensors keeps growing, I strongly recommend switching to fewer columns and more rows:

```
object_id, sensor_num, timestamp, float_value
```

Don't store `NULLs`.  Do have the first 3 columns as the `PRIMARY KEY'.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. The problem with your given code snippet is I may have selected different sensors from different tables. eg sensor1 from timeseries1, sensor10 from timeseries2. My apologies as I didn't mention it anywhere in my question. So it is like you have sensors 1 to 5 in timeseries1 table. sensors 6 to 10 in timeseries2 etc. Now when we select sensor1 and sensor8, they both belong to different tables and in such case above code snippet will not be handy.

Comment: timeseries?  object_ids?  sensors?  It sounds liek there are 3 components to the "id" for each sensor.  I lean toward a single table with (sensor_id, timestamp, value), where this sensor_id is the combination of timeseries+object_id+sensor_num.  More: https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_sensor

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Rick suggests, you might try adding these indexes to accelerate your original query examples.

```sql
CREATE INDEX s1dt ON timeseries (sensor1, datetime);
CREATE INDEX s2dt ON timeseries (sensor2, datetime);
```

They may help. They definitely generate index-employing execution plans on your test data set rather than table scans. https://dbfiddle.uk/XqE-lIvK

There are more elaborate solutions involving indexes on computed columns and that sort of thing. But try this first.

Comment: That gets into the limit of 64 secondary indexes; note that there are 1000 sensors.

Comment: Oh, I missed that the table is completely abnormalized.